# AngularJS broadcast Of $routeChangeSuccess fires twice in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to broadcast a route change to a directive:

```
function run($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
        function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
            if (current.$$route.originalPath !== '') {
                $rootScope.$broadcast(event.name, { loadedTemplateUrl: current.loadedTemplateUrl });
            }
        });
}
```

The directive is receiving the broadcast twice. The directive is placed upon an html template. There is no controller. How can I prevent from firing twice in directive?

```
    function optimizely($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
                function (event, data) {
                    var template = '';

                    switch (data.loadedTemplateUrl) {
                        case '/app/views/china.html':
                            template = '<script src=""></script>';
                            break;
                        default:
                            template = '<script src="App/optimizelyTest.js"></script>';
                    }

                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        var content = $compile(template)(scope);
                        element.append(content);
                    });
                });
        }
    };

    return directive;
}
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Have you tried logging the output of event, current, previous to the console to see if you get any hints? Nothing is glaring at me here. If you know how, creating a plunker (https://plnkr.co/) will help myself or somebody else troubleshoot.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this